# ¿Cómo evito que me aparezcan los indices en mi dataframe al imprimirlo?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, print

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo evito que me aparezcan los indices de este dataframe? La línea de código que lo muestra es la siguiente (Es un archivo de excel el que estoy importando):

```
print(dataframe.iloc[:, 0:2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el método [`pandas.DataFrame.to_string`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html) con el argumento `index` con valor `False`:

```
print(dataframe.iloc[:, 0:2].to_string(index=False))
```

> ```
>     Productos  Precio Unitario ($)
>     Camisetas                   10
>  Calentadores                   25
>        Gorras                    5
>     Sudaderas                   20
>  Pantalonetas                   15
> ```

Comment: Graciaaaaas!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!